# Partial Derivatives in Haskell

Tags: haskell, calculus

A while back a friend wanted help with a program that could solve for the roots of functions using Newton's method, and naturally for that I needed some way to calculate the derivative of a function numerically, and this is what I came up with:

```
deriv f x = (f (x+h) - f x) / h where h = 0.00001
```

Newton's method was a fairly easy thing to implement, and it works rather well. But now I've started to wonder - Is there some way I could use this function to solve partial derivatives in a numerical manner, or is that something that would require a full-on CAS? I would post my attempts but I have absolutely no clue what to do yet.

Please keep in mind that I am new to Haskell. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

You can certainly do much the same thing as you already implemented, only with multivariate perturbation instead. But first, as you should always do with top-level functions, add a type signature:

```
deriv :: (Double -> Double) -> Double -> Double
```

That's not the most general signature possible, but probably sufficiently general for everything you'll need. I'll call

```
type ℝ = Double
```

in the following for brevity, i.e.

```
deriv :: (ℝ -> ℝ) -> ℝ -> ℝ
```

Now what you want is, for example in ℝ²

```
grad :: ((ℝ,ℝ) -> ℝ) -> (ℝ,ℝ) -> (ℝ,ℝ)
grad f (x,y) = ((f (x+h,y) - f (x,y)) / h, (f (x,y+h) - f (x,y)) / h)
 where h = 0.00001
```

It's awkward to have to write out the components individually and make the definition specific to a particular-dimensional vector space. A [generic way](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.11/docs/Data-Basis.html) of doing it:

```
import Data.VectorSpace
import Data.Basis

grad :: (HasBasis v, Scalar v ~ ℝ) => (v -> ℝ) -> v -> v
grad f x = recompose [ (e, (f (x ^+^ h*^basisValue b) - f x) ^/ h)
                     | (e,_) <- decompose x ]
 where h = 0.00001
```

Note that this pre-chosen-step–finite-differentiation is always a tradeoff between inaccuracy from higher-order terms and from floating-point errors, so definitely check out automatic differentiation.

Answer (score 3):

This is called [automatic differentiation](https://wiki.haskell.org/Automatic_Differentiation) and there is a lot of really neat work in this area in Haskell, though I don't know how accessible it is.

From the wiki page:

- A paper [Beautiful Differentiation](http://conal.net/papers/beautiful-differentiation/) and the corresponding [talk](https://vimeo.com/album/126865/video/6622658).
- Forward mode libraries: [ad](http://hackage.haskell.org/cgi-bin/hackage-scripts/package/ad), [fad](http://hackage.haskell.org/cgi-bin/hackage-scripts/package/fad), [vector-space](https://wiki.haskell.org/Vector-space), [Data.Ring.Module.AutomaticDifferentiation](http://comonad.com/haskell/monoids/dist/doc/html/monoids/Data-Ring-Module-AutomaticDifferentiation.html)
- Reverse mode libraries: also [ad](http://hackage.haskell.org/cgi-bin/hackage-scripts/package/ad), [rad](http://hackage.haskell.org/cgi-bin/hackage-scripts/package/rad)